# Heredoc syntax in Rails migration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to put a trigger in a migration and have the following:

```
class AddUpdateTrigger < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change

    execute <<-SQL
        CREATE TRIGGER tsvectorupdate BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE
        ON queryables  FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE
        tsvector_update_trigger(
          search_data, 'pg_catalog.english', val
        );
     SQL  


  end
end
```

When I run `rake db:migrate`, I get the following error:

```
    rake aborted!
    SyntaxError: /Users/jt/repos/blue/db/migrate/20151215052427_add_update_trigger.rb:15:
    can't find string "SQL" anywhere before EOF
```

but I am not sure why. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You probably shouldn't be using the `change` method here. Rails wouldn't be able to roll it back properly.

Comment: @dan-klasson thx dan, I tend to just create a new change if I have to step out of a change. maintains temporal consistency and never had any problems doing it that way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have extra space characters after your intended closing `"SQL"`. It is actually `"SQL  "`, so it does not match the opening `"SQL"`.

Comment: cool, thx sawa. works great. really appreciate; have to wait a few minutes